# golang execute command error. tar: 'ttyout=progress %u\r': unknown checkpoint action

Tags: go, tar

I have a program that needs to execute the tar command and get the progress, but the command cannot be executed successfully. How can I fix it? What puzzles me is that it can be executed successfully in bash.

Here is my code.

```golang
func test() {

    cmd := exec.Command("tar", "zxvf", "backup.tar.gz", "--blocking-factor=94170", "--checkpoint=1", "--checkpoint-action='ttyout=progress %u\r'")

    var stdout bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &stdout
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Logger().Info("failed: ", err)
        log.Logger().Info(stderr.String())
    }

    log.Logger().Info(stdout.String())

}
```

I got an error in stderr:

```
failed: exit status 2
tar: 'ttyout=progress %u\r': unknown checkpoint action
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: May be try using literal string quotes instead? `\`--checkpoint-action='ttyout=progress %u\r'`\`

Comment: Or) `"--checkpoint-action=\"ttyout=progress %u\r\""`

Comment: Nothing has changed.

Comment: I think you may need to escape the backslash, `\\r`